# ODP.NET Memory Leak

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I apologize for a duplicate question. I found this issue from 5 years ago

[Memory Leak with OracleCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565681/memory-leak-with-oraclecommand)

but was unable to comment on it due to site restrictions. I also tried to see if I could contact the OP but couldn't figure out how, if it is even possible. Their problem does not appear to have ever been sufficiently answered.

I have been fighting with a memory leak for two weeks now just like the one mentioned where the ConnDataPool Hashtable never releases its memory (containing a LOT of UTF8CommandText objects).

All of my connections, commands, parameters, data readers, etc. are contained in Using blocks, but these objects keep lingering. Has anyone seen this? What was your solution?

Comment: Try calling Close and Dispose() on all your Oracle objects and see if that helps. Sometimes the garbage collector is too slow and since the ODP.NET you are using is probably unmanaged, the GC doesn't realize how much memory is being held.

Comment: We were calling close and dispose on the objects originally. Then I changed to use the 'Using' blocks, hoping it would remedy the problem. Obviously, it does not.

Comment: What is the full version of ODP.NET you are using? Make sure you are patched up to the latest, although aside from people not calling Dispose() it has been years since I have seen complaints about memory leaks.

Comment: This is curious.  I'm pretty bad about disposing, and I've never had any issues with memory leaks.  Can you post some sample code that will demonstrate the problem?  Include the types of command calls -- inserts, selects, stored procs, whatever...

Comment: Using ODP.NET 11.2.0.4, we have not upgraded to Oracle 12 yet.